# How to set starting point for matplotlib x axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm running into what appears to be a simple issue with using Seaborn/matplotlib, in that my x axis values do not appear to correlate correctly to the labels on the bars. For reference, I had a `pandas.DataFrame` object and dropped the first 20 rows to show a more detailed look at the data, leaving me with something like:

```
hypothesis1_df:

     revol_util  deviation
20           20 -37.978539
21           21 -27.313996
22           22 -23.790328
23           23 -19.729957
24           24 -16.115686
..          ...        ...
96           96  67.275585
97           97  91.489382
98           98  60.967792
99           99  48.385094
100         100  77.852812
```

Now the problem is when I graph this using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax = sns.barplot(x='revol_util', y='deviation', data=hypothesis1_df)
ax.set(xlabel="Revolving Credit Utilization (%)",
           ylabel="Deviation from Mean (%)",
           title="Credit Utilization and Likelihood of Late Payments\n(20 - 100%)")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))  # Format axis ticks as int
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(base=10)) # Set tick label frequency = base

plt.show()
```

I get this:

[image: Image1]

Note the x-axis values and how they're not starting at 20. Is there any way to offset the ticker? I tried `ax.set_xlim(xmin=20, xmax=100)` but that only chops off the bottom 20 of my graph and extends it 20 to the right into blank space. If I remove all axis formatting it's correctly labeled but way too busy since every label is listed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `fig.tight_layout()` or `plt.tight_layout()` worked for me~

Answer (score 0):

Since we know that the ticks in a seaborn barplot always start at 0, we can just add the first value of your `revol_util` values to the current ticks in a [`matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter), along with your existing `MultipleLocator`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# A fake dataframe
hypothesis1_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'revol_util':np.arange(20, 101, 1),
    'deviation':np.arange(-40, 81, 1.5) + np.random.rand(81)*10.})
hypothesis1_df = hypothesis1_df.set_index('revol_util', drop=False)

ax = sns.barplot(x='revol_util', y='deviation', data=hypothesis1_df)
ax.set(xlabel="Revolving Credit Utilization (%)",
           ylabel="Deviation from Mean (%)",
           title="Credit Utilization and Likelihood of Late Payments\n(20 - 100%)")

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(
    lambda x, pos: '{:g}'.format(x + hypothesis1_df['revol_util'].iloc[0])))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try: `ax.set_xticklabels(hypothesis1_df.index.tolist())`
to manually set the x-axis labels.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to give me labels evenly spread in the range 21-29 when used with the `MultipleLocator` as is, and if I remove the `MultipleLocator` line and try it then it just ends up being all values in the range (which is too busy to read). Using `ax.set_xticklabels(np.arange(20, 100, 10)` gives me the labels, but assigns them to the first 8 and leaves the rest blank.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `MultipleLocator` line after the `ax.set_xticklabels(hypothesis1_df.index.tolist()) ` line?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in a seaborn bar plot the bars are indeed positionned at `0,1,...,N-1`; and their labels are set with a `FixedLocator` to the numbers corresponding to the data.

An option may hence:
Use a multiple locator and set the ticklabels manually

```
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
    ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.tolist()[::10]) # take every tenth label from list
```